# I am having trouble using FileSystemWatcher [vb.net]

Tags: vb.net, filesystemwatcher

This is my first time using FileSystemWatcher, but it's not working. It doesn't trigger when a file is created in the monitored paths. My goal is to monitor changes in the Program File directories. I will compare files copied against an online list (which I download). I'm not finished with that part yet [what it will do if it finds a match]. What am I doing wrong?

I've also noticed some say that FSW is glitchy or has issues. If you think I should use something else, let me know.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Public Class Form1
Private WithEvents pFiles As FileSystemWatcher
Private WithEvents pFiles32 As FileSystemWatcher
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
    Me.ShowInTaskbar = False

    pFiles = New FileSystemWatcher("C:\Program Files", "*.*")
    pFiles.IncludeSubdirectories = True
    If Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem.Equals(True) Then
        pFiles32 = New FileSystemWatcher("C:\Program Files (x86)", "*.*")
        pFiles32.IncludeSubdirectories = True
    End If
End Sub

Sub badFiles(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs) Handles pFiles.Created
    MsgBox("Triggered in x64 folder!")
    Dim fileInfo = New FileInfo(e.FullPath)
    Dim createWord = fileInfo.Name.ToString()
    Dim myWebClient As New System.Net.WebClient
    myWebClient.DownloadFile("http://www.systemlookup.com/lists.php?list=1&type=filename&search=" & createWord & "&s=", "C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\" & createWord & ".html")
    Dim reader = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\" & createWord & ".html")
    If reader.Contains("No results. Please try a different search term.") Then
        MsgBox("Not Found!")
    Else
        If reader.Contains(createWord) Then
            MsgBox("Found!")
        Else
            MsgBox("Not Found!")
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Sub badFiles32(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs) Handles pFiles32.Created
    MsgBox("Triggered in x86 folder!")
    Dim fileInfo = New FileInfo(e.FullPath)
    Dim createWord = fileInfo.Name.ToString()
    Dim myWebClient As New System.Net.WebClient
    myWebClient.DownloadFile("http://www.systemlookup.com/lists.php?list=1&type=filename&search=" & createWord & "&s=", "C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\" & createWord & ".html")
    Dim reader = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\" & createWord & ".html")
    If reader.Contains("No results. Please try a different search term.") Then
        MsgBox("Not Found!")
    Else
        If reader.Contains(createWord) Then
            MsgBox("Found!")
        Else
            MsgBox("Not Found!")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You don't set up any event handlers for the `FileSystemWatcher` - `Changed`, `Created`, `Deleted`, `Renamed`.  It is triggering - there's just nothing for it to **do** when it triggers.

Comment: `Dim pFiles As FileSystemWatcher` overwrites the one declared as WithEvents.  that line should simply be `pFiles = New FileSystemWatcher`

Comment: Wait, I thought that's what happens when you add "Handles pFiles.Created"? I thought it runs the Sub upon creation?

Comment: @user287848 - Sorry, you are correct.  I didn't scroll over all the way to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are replacing your module level variables:

```
Private WithEvents pFiles As FileSystemWatcher
Private WithEvents pFiles32 As FileSystemWatcher

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
      ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ' this creates a NEW pfiles which only exists in FormLoad
    Dim pFiles As FileSystemWatcher = New FileSystemWatcher("C:\Program Files", 
           "*.*")
    pFiles.IncludeSubdirectories = True
```

Even you were to manually hook it up using `AddHandler`, *that* `pFiles` goes out of scope at the end of Form Load.  The correct syntax would be:

```
' since it is already declared (DIM) you just need to instance it (NEW):
pFiles = New FileSystemWatcher(...
```

Comment: Ah, you're right. I assume this is because the Sub is Private, yes? I guess I just blindly went with that because I saw some example code on MSDN put that in Form Load.

I'll try fixing it in a moment.

Comment: No, DIM declare a new variable in that procedure only.  you already have it declared at the top, so you only need to create an instance in Form load.  Variable `Scope` is determined by where they are declared (Dim, Private, Friend, Public)

Comment: Oh, I see what I did. I'm not accessing the class level pFiles variables, I created a one exclusive to Form Load... Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: exactly!  click the checkmark next to the answer if it works now, so this will be moved off the UnAnswered list.

Comment: I update my OP, take a look if that seems correct. I will test it out now.

Comment: yes, it looks right, but you should be using `Environment.GetFolderPath` to get folder names instead of using string literals

Comment: Yeah, that was another problem I was having. I was using Environment.GetFolderPath, but both ProgramFiles and ProgramFiles(x86) were coming up as "C:\Program Files(x86)". My OS is 64 bit, so there are two Program File directories. I figured I'd deal with that later.

Comment: I copied a file to the directories while the program was running, and nothing happened. I put a MsgBox in each Sub (BadFiles sub) to notify me that it was being triggered. No MsgBox appeared.

Comment: MsgBox is not the way to debug (ever), especially with this (ever * 2.  To start, just add "Console.Beep" but I dont think created is the same as COPYING a file.

Comment: How would you debug in this instance, to see if it's triggering? And is there an event handler for copying rather than creating, if there's a difference?

Comment: it works for me (and Copy does fire the Create).  you need to add `pfiles.EnableRaisingEvents = True` to activate it...in form load where you are configuring it.  you have a lot of other cruft in the event handler though - is it necessary to download a file and parse it for every event?  These things can fire pretty quickly in succession

Comment: Ugh, I hate missing that "Enable" property. Easy for me to miss. Thank you, that triggered the Sub routines!